# PHP copy folder from another place on ftp to new destination ø

Tags: php, mysql

I have made this script to generate 3 folders with Random names, and in the end, I paste a complete folder I have placed another place inside the ftp.

It really works great with the folders, but I can't make the copy paste in the end folder!

Can you explain how to fix it?

```
<?php    


                 $tags = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT domaine FROM `domains` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1; ") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($tags)) 
                             {            
                                 $domainresul =  $row['domaine'];
                             } 

                                function random_string($length) {
                                    $key = '';
                                    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));
                                    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
                                    $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
                                    }

                                    return $key;
                                }


                                $file = "index.php";
                                $content = $sideindhold;


                                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


                                $ftp_server = "xxx"; // virtuelt doamin
                                $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
                                $ftp_user_name = "xxx"; // bruger jeg har opsat på min xampp, med rettigheder til example.com
                                $ftp_user_pass = "xxx";
                                $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

                                // $root="url/phptest";
                                $root = $domainresul;




                                /* **************************************** */
                                /* create a stream context telling PHP to overwrite the file */
                                $options = array('ftp' => array('overwrite' => true));
                                $stream = stream_context_create($options);
                                /* **************************************** */


                                // check connection
                                echo "<center>";
                                if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
                                echo '<div style="background-color:red;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;">';
                                echo "FTP connection has failed!";
                                echo "Attempted to connect to <b>$ftp_server</b> for user <b>$ftp_user_name</b>";
                                echo '</div>';
                                } else {

                                $foldername1 = random_string(4);
                                $foldername2 = random_string(3);
                                $foldername3 = random_string(2);



                                $directory = "$root/$foldername1";

                                if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $directory)) {

                                $directory = "$root/$foldername1/$foldername2";

                                if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $directory)) {

                                $directory = "$root/$foldername1/$foldername2/$foldername3";


                                if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $directory)) {
                                /* **************************************** */
                                /* and finally, put the contents */
                                $hostname2 = "ftp://" . $ftp_user_name . ":" . $ftp_user_pass . "@" . $ftp_server . "/";
                     $hostname = "ftp://" . $ftp_user_name . ":" . $ftp_user_pass . "@" . $ftp_server . "/" . $directory . "/";


                       $src = $hostname2 . "xxx.xxx/se";
                       $dst = $hostname;

                       echo $src;
                       echo $dst;

                       shell_exec("cp -r $src $dest");

                     /* **************************************** */

                 }
             }
         } else {
             echo '<div style="background-color:red;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px">';
             echo "Could not create directory: <b>$directory</b>";
             echo '</div>';
         }
     }
     echo "</center>";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: what does this mean: "i can't make the copy paste in the end folder"? You're code only creates random folder names. It does not try to copy or move any other folders, so it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I try to take a random donain from mysql crate 3 folders behind together and in the end i try to make a copy og another folder whit files i have placed antoher place in the ftp!

Comment: I don't see any code trying to copy files from another place in the FTP, so it obviously isn't going to do that. Are you just asking how to copy files via FTP?

Comment: Look at $src og $dst

Comment: $hostname2 = "ftp://" . $ftp_user_name . ":" . $ftp_user_pass . "@" . $ftp_server . "/";
                     $hostname = "ftp://" . $ftp_user_name . ":" . $ftp_user_pass . "@" . $ftp_server . "/" . $directory . "/";


                       $src = $hostname2 . "xxx.xxx/se";
                       $dst = $hostname;

                       echo $src;
                       echo $dst;

                       shell_exec("cp -r $src $dest");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're shell_exec() command is running on the local machine. "cp -r" is for copying files locally; it does not handle remote ftp:// urls.

You need to use [`ftp_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-exec.php). The copy code would look something like:

```
$src = "xxx.xxx/se";
$dst = $directory . "/" . $src;

ftp_exec("cp -r $src $dst");
```